# Generating a link dynamicaly according with dropdown list value

Tags: javascript, mootools, joomla2.5, chronoforms

I am using Joomla 2.5 with Mootools and a plugin (Chronoforms) to create a tabbed form.Right now I have a dropdown menu that is loading some data from the DB via PHP. I have a button that I wish could load some values depending on the value of the dropdown, so I tried:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('province_aw').addEvent('change', function() {
        document.getElementById('link1').href = "index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=listSpecific-3&id_province="+index+"&id_ch="+b;
    });
});
```

with this button

```
<a class="jcepopup" id="link1" href="javascript:void(0);" rel="{handler:'iframe'}"> <input type='button' name='prueba' id='prueba' value='...' /> </a>
```

The dropdown is actually changing the value of the links HREF, but it keeps opening a blank `iframe` everytime I click on it.

Comment: Does your link/`href` open a iFrame with adress index.php? there is no domain in your url... that can be the problem, or do you have a `<base>` tag?

Comment: as i said, the mootools/js function changes the HREF, but it keeps opening a blank iframe (not redirecting to index.php)

Comment: Can you post more html? the select and the iframe at least. Did you try adding the whole url to the link? (the part before the index.php)

Comment: sergio can i send u a PM with the link to the form?

Comment: Did you get it working? you can mail me, bust best is to post here so more people can help.

Comment: Here is the link to the form, i would like the top dropdown to affect the behavior of the button on the bottom. thanks [link]http://bridgebuilders.info/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdown already works, it changes the button and if you right click to open the link in a new tab/window it works good.

Your problem is elsewhere, not in the code you posted. I suggest checking your jQuery script, in my console its not complete, it ends in the middle of a function, looks like a broken file. Check also the jcemediabox-popup-iframe, check for versions and opening it with simple content for debugging.

Comment: @Brandon, but did it work for you also to right click on it? And the jQuery library, is the file ok?

Comment: i checked all the mootools and debugged a little, but the problem still persists. As you can see, there are other buttons in the middle of the form (which i'm generating via PHP), and i managed to changed the value of the HREF, but it doesn't change the actual action the button performed. I had it configured to open one table, and when i change with the dropdown it doesn't update the db call.

Comment: Since i'm using Chronoforms, i'm relying on the Mootools framework, no jQuery

Comment: I checked the form without the iframe, [link]http://bridgebuilders.info/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&tmpl=component&chronoform=application and is working fine, so the problem is located with the iframe itself, but i can't figure out where. To create said frame i'm using JCE popup.

Comment: still not working, thinking it might be related to the JCE popup and not the code itself

Comment: @Brandon, will check it also.

Comment: @Brandon, yes I think it's related with the JCE popup too. Is the script for it inside the same as Mootools More?

Comment: gotit working with a long turn, using the jcepopup.open function.THANKS.OBRIGADO